# log4j logger is not logging anything when log.info() is called

Tags: log4j2, vert.x

I have this in:

> main/resources/log4j.properties

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

and I call it using:

```
package huru.middleware;

import huru.MainVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class JWTHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

  private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainVerticle.class);

  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
    HttpServerRequest request = ctx.request();
    log.info("in the jwt middleware");
    System.out.println("DOOOOF");
    System.out.println(ctx.request().method());
    ctx.next();
  }
}
```

System.out.println calls will get logged, but log.info() doesn't log anything. Anyone know what might be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quickfix would be to change the `log4j.properties` a tiny bit:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: ok so add stdout to the rootLogger line? what weird config it is, before the days of JSON I guess

Comment: I am not really sure what the appender stuff is for tbh

Comment: do you know a good way to change the config based on env vars? I hear you can do something like `log4j.rootLogger = ${root_logger_level}, stdout`